# Phonegap App won't install from Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have built the App local, I can install it directly on my android device without a problem.
It uploads to Google Play without a problem.

But when a user on any android device gets it from Google Play it won't install, it just gives "error: -24". Even on devices where the app hasn't been before (so no data bug).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photoflirtapp

Answer (score 0):

It's Certificate error.

You probably have another version of the App installed in your device. Remove that and retry.

Reference: http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-1-4-2-4-3-jelly-bean/292379-google-play-unkown-error-code-24-a.html

Comment: Ok, Certificate error gives me something to look at.
But it also happens on devices that haven't installed the app before.